# Cordova project: allowBackup is set to false, but can still take an adb backup

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic3, android-manifest

I want to disable the ability to take an *adb backup* file from our Cordova / Ionic app. I have added the plugin *cordova-plugin-allow-backup* to our project which has worked successfully; confirmed this by building a release version of the APK and installing it to my Android device, then checking the AndroidManifest.

[image]
However, when I run the following command, I can still take a backup despite explicitly setting this property to *false*:

`adb backup -f company.ab com.company.sales`

Should I be able to take a backup at this point? Am I looking at the wrong property? Any guidance here would be appreciated.

The device I'm testing on is a Samsung Galaxy Tab Active2, that's running Android 7.1.1.

Thanks,
bengrah.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question too. but after seeing [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#allowbackup) description, I just began to think this is the right behavior.
Which means you can't disable the ADB backup feature but your app won't participate in this infrastructure.
In my case, I can still backup but the backup file's size is extremely small which I guess nothing is in there.

> Whether to allow the application to participate in the backup and
>   restore infrastructure. If this attribute is set to false, no backup
>   or restore of the application will ever be performed, even by a
>   full-system backup that would otherwise cause all application data to
>   be saved via ADB. The default value of this attribute is true.

Comment: I can confirm that the `adb backup` command runs without an issue. But the resulting backup file is extremely small. Also, when you extract it using [Android backup extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor#readme) the resulting `tar` file can't be unpacked.

Comment: As far as I can tell `allowBackup` set to `false` does two things: it disables [Auto Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup) and [Key/Value Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup) for your app and using `adb backup` on the app results in an empty backup.